# JNI crash on env->NewObject sometimes?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create an object in C and passing it to the jvm.

The java object is like this:

```
package mypackage;
public class Blub {
  public Blub(float a, float b) {
    // storing the floats
  }
}
```

The C side initializes with:

```
jclass Blub_class = env->FindClass("mypackage/Blub");
jmethodID Blub_constructor = env->GetMethodID(Blub_class, "<init>", "(FF)V");
```

And creates an instance with:

```
jobject myInstance = env->NewObject(Blub_class, Blub_constructor, 0, 0);
```

And here it fails most of the times - sometimes it succeeds..?
Its really strange - if it works it works for the whole run of the program, if it does not it fails on the first execution of NewObject

Some additional info:

- The NewObject invoking thread is attached to the jvm
- env is the thread's local reference to the jvm
- Blub_class and Blub_constructor were fetched and stored by another thread
- the initializing thread is guranteed to initialize way before NewObject is invoked
- In the debugger every parameter to NewObject seems ok

For now I'm working around this issue by just invoking methods with only primitive parameters on the jvm - which works fine.

I really don't know what I miss -.- Is there something wrong with what I do?

additionally here is how it fails:

```
V  [jvm.dll+0x14a6a6]
C  [mylib.dll+0x1fae9]  JNIEnv_::NewObject+0x59
```

Comment: The problem is the `jclass` stored by another thread. That object reference can become stale. You can't retain object refer noes across JNI calls like that: see the documentation. Write the code as above in the same thread, or else waste memory and use a `GlobalRef` for it.